# Is the aleph bet of Ben sira canonical?

Tags: midrash, mesorah-tradition, apocrypha

Is [אלפא ביתא אחרת לבן סירא](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim,_The_Aleph_Bet_of_ben_Sira,_The_Alphabet_of_ben_Sira,_(alternative_version).1) (excluding the passages brought in the gemara) in the sefer אוצר מדרשים part of the jewish mesorah?

Specifically this passage:

> כתיב עושה גדולות עד אין חקר ונפלאות עד אין מספר בא וראה כמה גדולים מעשיו של הקב״ה. אם נאמר עושה גדולות עד אין חקר למה נאמר ונפלאות עד אין מספר, ואם נאמר ונפלאות עד אין מספר למה נאמר עושה גדולות עד אין חקר? כיצד פירשו חז״ל עושה גדולות עד אין חקר כנגד כל יצירות שבעולם, ונפלאות עד אין מספר כנגד שלשה שנולדו בלא שכיבת הורתן עם אדם, ואלו הם בן סירא ורב פפא ורבי זירא (היוחסין מביא המעשה בערך אבוה בשם ר׳ יהודה החסיד, ועי' צמח דוד ח"א ג״א תמ״ח), וכלם צדיקים גמורים היו וחכמים גדולים בתורה, ואמרו עליהם על רבי זירא ועל רב פפא שמימיהם לא שחו שיחת חולין, ולא ישנו בבית המדרש לא שינת קבע ולא שינת עראי, ולא קידמן אדם לבית המדרש, ולא מצאן אדם יושבין ושותקין אלא יושבין ושונין, ולא בטלו מקדוש היום, ולא כנו שם רע לחביריהם, ולא נתכבדו בקלון חביריהם, ולא עלתה קללת חביריהם על מטתם, ולא נסתכלו בצלם דמות רשע, ולא קבלו מתנות, ותרנין היו לקיים מה שנאמר להנחיל אוהבי יש ואוצרותיהם אמלא (בתלמוד רשומות המדות האלה על חכמים שונים, עי׳ מגילה כ״ז: כ״ח.). והאיך ילדתן אמן בלא בעל? אמרו פעם אחת הלכו לבית המרחץ ונכנס לה בקובתן זרע מישראל ונתעברו וילדו מהם ולא היו יודעים מי היה אביהם, אבל בן סירא נודע לו מי היה אביו והאיך ילדתו אמו בלא בעילת בעל. אמרו עליה כי בת ירמיהו היתה, פעם אחת הלך ירמיה לבית המרחץ ומצא שם רשעים משבט אפרים וראה כי כלם מוציאין שכבת זרע לבטלה, לפי שכל שבט אפרים באותו הדור רשעים היו, שכן כתיב בו ויעש הרע בעיני ה', וכיון שראה אותם התחיל להוכיחם מיד קמו עליו ואמרו מפני מה הוכחתני חי דרך באר שבע שלא תזוז מכאן עד שתעשה כמונו. אמר להם הניחו לי ואשבע לכם שלא אגלה דבר זה לעולם, אמרו לו והלא צדקיהו ראה לנבוכדנצר אוכל ארנבת חיה ונשבע לו בגזירת השם שלא יגלה עליו ובטל שבועתו (נדרים ס״ה: איכה רבה פ׳ ישבו לארץ), וכן תעשה גם אתה, ועתה אם תעשה כמונו הרי טוב ואם לאו נעשה בך מעשה סדום כשם שעשו אבותינו בע״ז שלהם, ואם בע״ז היו עושין כך אנו בך על אחת כמה וכמה, מיד עשה כן מרוב הפחד והיראה מהם, וכמו שיצא משם התחיל לקלל יומו שנאמר ארור היום אשר יולדתי בו, ויצא והתענה על דבר זה רמ״ח תעניות כנגד כל איברים שבאדם, ושמורה היתה טיפה של אותו צדיק עד שבאתה בתו של אותו צדיק לבית המרחץ ונכנסה בקובתה, ולשבעה חדשים ילדה בן בשינים ובדיבור, וכיון שילדה היתה מתביישת מבני אדם שהיו אומרים מזנות ילדה, ופתח פיו הנער ואמר לאמו, על מה מתביישת מבני אדם כי בן סירא אני, אמרה לו סירא זה מי הוא? אמר לה ירמיהו, ולמה נקרא סירא שהוא שר על כל השרים והוא עתיד ליתן שם לכל שר ומלך, וכשתחשוב סירא וירמיהו בגימטריא שוין. אמרה לו בני אם כן היה לך לומר בן ירמיהו אני, אמר לה וכן הייתי רוצה לומר אלא שגנאי הדבר לומר ירמיהו בא על בתו, אמרה לו בני והא כתיב מה שהיה הוא שיהיה ומי ראה בת יולדת מאביה, אמר לה אמי אין כל חדש תחת השמש, מה לוט צדיק גמור אף אבי צדיק גמור, מה ללוט נעשה באונס אף לאבי נעשה באונס, אמרה לו תומהת אני ממך איך תדע דברים הללו, אמר לה אל תתמהי ממני שאין כל חדש תחת השמש, והרי ירמיהו אבי כך עשה בשעה שהיתה אמו כורעת לילד פתח פיו וקרא אבי ממעי אמו, ואמר לא אצא עד שתאמרו לי שמי, פתח אביו פיו ואמר צא ויקרא שמך אברהם, אמר לא כן שמי, אמר לו יקרא שמך יצחק יעקב וכן כל השבטים וכל אנשי הדור ההוא, ואמר לא כן שמי, עד שנזדמן שם אליהו ז״ל ואמר יקרא שמך ירמיה, שבימיך יקים הקב״ה אויב שירם ידו על ירושלם. [אמר לו כך שמי] ואתה שאמרת [לי שמי] יקרא שמי על שמך יהא לי משמך "יהו" ויקרא שמי ירמ-יהו, מה הוא יצא בדיבור אף אני יצאתי בדיבור, מה הוא יצא בנבואה ממעי אמו שנאמר בטרם אצרך בבטן ידעתיך וגו' אף אני יצאתי בנבואה, מה הוא יצא בשמו ממעי אמו אף אני יצאתי בשמי ממעי אמי, מה הוא עשה ספר באלפא ביתא (איכה) אף אני אעשה ספר באלפא ביתא, ועכשיו אל תתמהי מדברי. אמרה לו בני אל תדבר שלא ישלוט בך עין הרע, אמר לה אין עין הרע רשאה לשלטאה בי, ועתה אל תרבי [לדבר] עלי שאני עושה מה שעשה אבי, ועלי נאמר רחילא בתר רחילא אזלא וברא בתר עובדיה דאבוהי. אמרה לו בני מפני מה אתה מונע אותי מדיבור, אמר לה מפני שאת יודעת שאני רעב ואינך נותנת לי לאכול כלום, אמרה לו והרי לך דדים אכול מאכלך ושתה משתך, אמר לה אין לי חפץ בדדיך אלא לכי ובררי קמח כתרנגולא ולושי לחם נקי ובשר שמן ויין ישן ותאכלי עמי ביחד, אמרה לו ומהיכן אקנה דברים אלו, אמר לה עשי בגדים ומכרי ויתקיים בך הפסוק סדין עשתה ותמכור, ואם את מפרנסת אותי יתקיים בך הפסוק רבות בנות עשו חיל ואת עלית על כולנה. התחילה לעשות בגדים ומוכרת, ומביאה לו לחם ובשר שמן ויין ישן וכלכלתו שנה אחת, ולאחר השנה אמר לה הוליכני לבית הכנסת, והוליכה אותו לבית מלמד אחד שהיו לו שבע בנות, ישב בצדו ואמר לו רבי למדני תורה, אמר לו עדיין אין אתה בר לימוד כי קטון אתה, ואמרו חז״ל בן חמש שנים למקרא. אמר לו בן סירא ולא למדת היום קצר והמלאכה מרובה, ואתה אומר לי שב ולא תלמוד עדיין כי קטון אתה, ואני רואה בבית הקברות קטנים ממנו מתים, ומי יודע מה יהיה אם אחיה ואם אמות. אמר לו המלמד מפני מה אתה מורני ואמרו חז״ל כל המורה הלכה בפני רבו חייב מיתה, אמר לו עד כאן אינך רבי ועד כאן לא למדתי ממך כלום, אמר לו המלמד לבן סירא אמור אל״ף, השיב לו ואמר:
> It is written, (Job 9:10)  "Who performs great deeds which cannot be fathomed, And wondrous things without number."  Come and see how great are the Holy Blessed One's deeds! Since it says,  "Who performs great deeds which cannot be fathomed,"  why does it also say  "And wondrous things without number"?  And since it says  "And wondrous things without number,"  why does it also say  "Who performs great deeds which cannot be fathomed"?  How have the Sages interpreted it?  "Who performs great deeds which cannot be fathomed,"  refers to all the created beings in the world,  "And wondrous things without number,"  refers to the three beings who were born without their parents having mortal sex. And these are they: Ben Sira, Rav Papa, and Rabbi Zeira. (The "Yuchasin" brings the matter regarding Rabbi Judah the Pious's father, see further Tzemach David Part 1 1:448) They are all completely righteous ones, and wise, and great Torah scholars. And they said about Rabbi Zeria and Rav Papa that they never once spoke of worldly matters; and never slept in the Hall of Study, neither fully sleeping nor napping; and nobody ever showed up to the Hall of Study earlier than they did; and nobody ever found them sitting quietly instead of sitting and reciting Torah; and they never missed Kiddush; and they never gave their friends nasty nicknames; and never took honor from their friends' shame; and never even cursed their friends from their beds; and never looked at the image of an evil person; and didn't accept gifts; and these two both fulfill what is said: (Proverbs 8:22)  "I endow those who love me with substance; I will fill their treasuries."  (The Talmud lists these qualities about other Sages, see further in Megillah 27b-28a.) And how did their mothers give birth without husbands? They said: Once they went to the bathhouse, and some seed from an Israelite entered their bellies, and they conceived and gave birth from this, without knowing who their fathers were. But Ben Sira's father was known to him! How did his mother give birth without a husband's intercourse? They said about her that she was the daughter of Yirmiyahu. Once, Yirmiyahu went to the bathhouse, and found there evildoers from the tribe of Ephraim, and he saw that they were all wasting their seed, because the whole tribe of Ephraim in that generation were evildoers, as it is written about them that they did what was wrong in God's eyes. And when he saw them, he began to rebuke them. Immediately, they rose up against him, and said, "Why are you rebuking us? We swear by the road to Bethlehem that you will not leave here until you do what we are doing." He said to them, "Leave me alone and I will swear to you that I will never reveal this situation." They said to him, "Didn't Tzidkiyahu see Nevuchadnetzar eating a live rabbit, and swear to him in God's name that he would not reveal his secret, and then nullify that oath? (Nedarim 65b, Eicha Rabbah s.v.: "they sit on the ground") You will do the same thing! But now, if you do what we are doing, good, and not, we will do the Sodomite act to you, like our ancestors did for idolatrous purposes. If they did it for idolatry, how much more so should we do it to you!" Immediately, he did it, out of great terror and fear of them. When he began leaving there, he started to curse his birthday, saying (Jeremiah 20:14)  "Accursed be the day That I was born!"  He left there, and fasted for this incident 248 fasts, parallel to all the organs of a man. And the drop that came from that righteous man was guarded until that righteous man's own daughter came to the bathhouse, and it entered her belly. At seven months, she gave birth to a son who had teeth and could speak, and once she gave birth, she developed shame around people, because they would say that she gave birth through promiscuity. The child opened his mouth and said to his mother, "Why are you ashamed around people? I am the son of Sira." She said, "Who is Sira?" He said, "Yirmiyahu, and the reason he is called Sira is because he is the officer (sar) over all officers, and because he will ultimately name all officers and kings, and when you calculate 'Sira' and 'Yirmiyahu' in numerical values, they are equal." She said to him, "My son, if this is true, you should have said, 'I am the son of Yirmiyahu.'" He said to her, "I would have wanted to say that, but it is a shameful thing, saying that Yirmiyahu has had sex with his daughter." She said to him, "My son, is it not written (Ecclesiastes 1:9)  "Only that shall happen Which has happened,"  and who has ever seen a daughter have a child by her father?" He said to her, "My mother, (Ecclesiastes 1:9)  'There is nothing new Beneath the sun!'  Just as Lot was a completely righteous man, my father is also a completely righteous man. Just like Lot did it under compulsion, my father also had this done under compulsion." She said to him, "I am stunned by you. How do you know these things?" He said to her, "Do not be stunned by me, because there is nothing new beneath the sun. The same thing occurred with my father Yirmiyahu when his mother was kneeling to give birth- he opened his mouth, and my father called from his mother's innards, and said, 'I will not leave until you tell me my name.' His father opened his mouth and said, 'Come out, and your name will be Avraham' and he said, 'That is not my name.' He said, 'Come out, and your name will be Yitzchak...' and then Yaakov and all the tribes, and all the men of that generation, and he kept saying, 'That is not my name.' Until Eliyahu of Blessed Memory arrived there, and said, 'Your name will be Yirmiyah, because in your days the Holy Blessed One will establish an enemy to raise (yarim) his hand against Jerusalem.' He said, 'That is my name. And you, who told me my name, let your name be my name- let me have "yahu" from your name, and call me Yirmi-yahu.' Just as he was emerged speaking, I also emerged speaking; just as he emerged with prophecy from his mother's innards, as it is said, (Jeremiah 1:5)  'Before I created you in the womb, I selected you' ; just as he wrote an alphabetical acrostic book (Eicha), I also will write an alphabetical acrostic book, so not do not but stunned by my speech." She said, "My son, do not say it, so the Evil Eye will not reign over you!" He said to her, "The Evil Eye has no permission to reign over me, so now do not keep talking to me, for I am going to do what my father did. It is about me that it is said, (Ketubot 63a) 'One ewe follows another,' and a son follows his father's deeds." She said to him, "My son, why are you stopping me from talking?" He said, "Because you know that I am hungry, and you do not let me eat anything." She said to him, "Here are breasts for you- eat your food and drink your drink." He said to her, "I have no interest in your breasts. Rather, go and sift through flour like a hen, knead fine bread and fatty meat, and old wine, and you must eat together with me." She said to him, "But how could I buy things like this?" He said to her, "Make clothes and sell them, and the verse will be upheld for you: (Proverbs 31:24)  'She makes cloth and sells it.'  and if you support me, the verse (Proverbs 31:29), 'Many women have done well, But you surpass them all' will be true." She began to make clothes and sell them, and she would bring him bread and fatty meat, and old wine, and she supported him for one year. And after that year, he said to her, "Bring me to the synagogue," so she brought him to the house of one educator who had seven daughters. He sat beside him, and said to him, "Rabbi, teach me Torah!" He said to him, "You are not yet eligible to study, because you are so small, and our Sages z"l said (Pirkei Avot 5:21): 'A child of five should study Written Torah.'" Ben Sira said to him, "And have you not learned that (Pirkei Avot 2:15) 'the day is short, and the work is plentiful'? And you are telling me 'Sit and do not learn yet because you are so small,' while I see in the cemetery those smaller than me who have died, and who knows what will be, whether I will live or I will die?" The educator said to him, "What, are you my teacher? Haven't our Sages z"l said: "Anyone who teaches halacha in front of their Rabbi is liable for the death penalty'?" He said to him, "So far, you are not my Rabbi and so far, I have learned nothing from you." The educator said to Ben Sira, "Say, 'Aleph.'" He responded to him, saying:

Comment: What is "the jewish mesorah"?

Comment: Also, there's a difference between your title question and the one in the body of the text. Are you asking about the whole collection or about that particular text?

Comment: @Harel13 If one section is not good how can the rest be trusted?

Comment: One random example that comes to mind is the usage of the Tannaim and Amoraim of the real Sefer Ben Sira (not the midrash you're asking about). Quotes and paraphrases of the book can be found throughout the mishna, gemara and various midrashim. However, in [Sanhedrin 100b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.100b.3-11?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) Rav Yosef states that Ben Sira should not be read because some of its content is problematic. However, past uses of the book were still kept in all of the above-mentioned sources.

Comment: So, one section does not necessarily cancel out the rest. Nor do we say that the mishna, gemara, midrashim should be burned because they quoted from Ben Sira. Ironically, the passage with Rav Yosef brings a mass of such quotes. By the way, I don't know if you're aware, but Otzar Midrashim is an early 20th century compilation of many different little-known or long-lost midrashim, compiled by Y.D. Eisenstein. As a compilation, It's not an ancient one like Midrash Hagadol or Yalkut Shimoni. The texts themselves are old, of course.

Comment: @Harel13 I was not aware of its date of compilation.  Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @DoubleAA The Jewish mesorah is what we consider to be consistent with the teachings of the torah.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148365/discussion-between-harel13-and-shababnik).

Comment: @Shababnik Tautological platitudes aren't going to help you. The point is you haven't provided a rigorous standard that we can evaluate this text by. Who or what determines if a text is canonical? Consider Midrash Rabba, Maccabees, pseudo-Jonathan, the Zohar, or mendelsohn's biur. What are you really looking for?

Comment: I'm looking if the passage in question is to be considered emet

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not one to define the standards of Jewish teachings. That precisely is my question